# Sup and inf and boundary of this set

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have to find $\sup$, $\inf$ and $\partial A$ of the set

$$ A = \left\{ (-1)^n \frac{n^2+1}{2n^2+3}:\ n\in\mathbb{N} \right\}$$

So as $n\to +\infty$ we oscillate between $\pm \frac{1}{2}$. Those are its limit points, but they do not belong to $A$, hence $A$ cannot be closed.
This means that whatever is its boundary is not (entirely) contained in $A$.

I have managed to prove that $$\bigg| \frac{n^2+1}{2n^2+4}\bigg| \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

hence the set is bounded, because it does exist an upper bound and a lower bound.

I am not sure how to prove that $\frac{1}{2}$ is also the supremum (but it's not the max since it does not belong to $A$).

So I thought to define $a_n = (-1)^n \frac{n^2+1}{2n^2+3}$ and hence $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists n_0$ such that $a_n \geq \frac{1}{2}-\epsilon$.

Say $n_0$ is even, hence $n_0 = 2k_0$ for some $k_0$. Then

$$a_{2k_0} = \frac{4k_0^2+1}{8k_0^2 + 3} \geq \frac{1}{2}-\epsilon$$

This means $k_0^2 > \frac{1}{16\epsilon} - \frac{3}{8}$.

Here I got stuck because I'm still incompetent and I cannot interpret and give sense to this result, assuming it has any...

- On the other side, I have totally no clue about how to find the boundary...

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: Use long division to rewrite the fraction as $(-1)^n\left (\frac 12 - \frac {1}{2(2n^2+3)} \right )$.  I believe you'll find it significantly easier to analyze the expression's asymptotic behavior in this form.

Comment: Another approach for the same idea:  Try consider subsequences on odds and evens. One will be Rise to -1/2 second lower to 1/2.

Comment: @RobertShore I already studied the behavious at infinity and I found its limit points... Are they its boundary too? How can I prove this? It's not always true that limit points are bondary points, is it?

Comment: In this form, you can readily see that $\vert a_n \vert \lt \frac 12$ and that $\vert a_n \vert$ is monotonically increasing.  That should help you determine the boundary.  If $\vert x \vert \gt \frac 12$, can you necessarily find an open ball that's disjoint from the sequence?

Comment: @RobertShore Can I also say the set is not closed because not every convergent sequence converge to elements in the set, like $x_n = \frac{1}{2} + n$? Anywy, I think it's boundary is $\{ -1/2, 1/2\}$

Comment: @RobertShore Oh wait! I would instead say that since $A$ is just a union of slinglets, then it's boundary is all $A$ except for the two points $\pm 1/2$. But this would mean $A$ is not closed (as it is). Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $a\leq\frac12$ for every $a\in A$. This tells us that $\frac12$ is an upper bound of $A$.

Secondly observe that for every $r<\frac12$ we can show that $r$ is **not** an upper bound of $A$. This because an element $a\in A$ can be found with $r<a$.

This together proves that $\frac12$ is the least upperbound (i.e. supremum) of $A$.

In a similar way it can be proved that $-\frac12$ is the greatest lowerbound (i.e. infinum) of $A$.

Observe that the closure of $A$ is the set $A\cup\left\{-\frac12,\frac12\right\}$ and observe that the closure of $A^c=\mathbb R-A$ is $\mathbb R$.

Then for the [boundary](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoundaryPoint.html#:%7E:text=A%20point%20which%20is%20a,closure%20of%20its%20complement%20set.) of $A$ we find:$$\partial A=\overline A\cap\overline{A^c}=A\cup\left\{-\frac12,\frac12\right\}$$

Comment: That was really enlightening!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Let me say one thing more about isolated points of a set $A$. In another question you wondered whether they are elements of the boundary of $A$. Mostly they do but not always. If we deal with discrete topology then the boundary of *every* set is empty. But next to that *every* point of a set can be recognized as an isolated point of that set.

Answer (score 1):

For even $n=2k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, note
$$ (-1)^n \frac{n^2+1}{2n^2+3}=\frac{4k^2+1}{8k^2+3}=\frac12\frac{k^2+\frac14}{k^2+\frac38}<\frac12 $$
and
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{4k^2+1}{8k^2+3}=\frac12. $$
Also
$$ \bigg(\frac{4x^2+1}{8x^2+3}\bigg)'=\frac{8x}{(8x^2+3)^2}>0, x\ge1. $$
Thus $\bigg\{\frac{4k^2+1}{8k^2+3}\bigg\}$ tends strictly increasingly to $\frac12$ and hence for $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ \frac12-\varepsilon<\frac{4k_0^2+1}{8k_0^2+3}<\frac12 $$
or
$$ \frac12-\varepsilon<a_{2k_0}<\frac12. $$
So $\sup A=\frac12$. Note $\frac12$ is a boundary point since there are points in $A$ and not in $A$ in any neighborhood of $\frac12$. You can use the same way to show $\inf A=-\frac12$ and $-\frac12$ is a boundary point of $A$ too.

Comment: Can I say the boundary of $A$ is $A$ itself except for the points $\pm 1/2$, hence it's not closed?

Comment: The boundary of $A$ is $\{\pm\frac12\}$. All points of $A$ are dangling points.

Comment: What is a "dangling point"? o.O

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Thank you. Though I dont' understand why other points in $A$ are not boundary points too. For example for $n = 0$ (we assume it in the naturals) we have $1/3$. Any neighbourhood of $1/3$ contains points in $A$ and not in $A$, for example $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{127}}$

Comment: Am I right? I don't see why the other points of $A$ should be names in such a never-heard way (dangling points) and not just boundary...

Comment: What is the definition of boundary points?

Comment: $x\in A$ is a dangling point of $A$ if there is neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N\cap A=\{x\}$.

Comment: Well as I said above, a boundary point is a point for which any of its neighbourhoods contain a point in $A$ and a point in $A^c$, hence it sounds like it fits to me. Any neighbourhood of $1/3$ (say) contains $1/3$ which is in $A$ and other points which are not in $A$

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) (and more sources) the boundary of $A$ is its closure minus its interior. Further AFAIK boundary points of $A$ are elements of the boundary of $A$. Also see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoundaryPoint.html#:~:text=A%20point%20which%20is%20a,closure%20of%20its%20complement%20set.). So in this situation every element of $A$ is also a boundary point of $A$. You only seem to accept limit points of $A$ as boundary points but I don't think that is common. Do you have a reference to what you call "dangling points"?

Comment: @drhab: A point $x$ is a boundary point of a set $A ⊂ X$ if there are points
arbitrarily close to $x$ that are in $A$ and if there are points arbitrarily close to x that are in $X$ but not in $A$. See https://are.berkeley.edu/courses/ARE211/fall2012/lecture_notes/mathAnalysis5-12-draft.pdf